# Generalization of Binomial Coefficients Congruence

Tags: number-theory, binomial-coefficients

It is well known and not hard to prove that $\binom{pA}{pB}\equiv\binom{A}{B}\mod p$ where $p$ is a prime. Now, how can we extend to show that this congruence holds $\mod p^2$.

Finally, can we extend this to $\binom{pA+a}{pB+b}\equiv\binom{A}{B}\binom{a}{b}\mod p$?

Comment: http://www.dms.umontreal.ca/~andrew/PDF/BinCoeff.pdf

Answer (score 1):

You cannot show that it holds modulo $p^2$ because it is wrong (try $A=p$ and $B=1$).

Your second question is just Lucas theorem for $a$ and $b$ at most $p-a$.

See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lucas%27_theorem

Comment: Is there a proof of this without Lucas' theorem that relies solely on elementary facts (Binomial theorem, etc.)

Comment: @sm654567 I am not sure what you mean. What you want is usually the key lemma in any proof of Lucas theorem and it only uses elementary facts, the binomial theorem and the fact that $p$ does not divide factorials of smaller numbers.